# Как сделать симетричнный скос

Tags: blender

У меня есть объект где размер одной стороны больше другой,
я сделал скос с помощью горячих клавиш Ctrl+B, но получилось не то, что хотел:

На скриншоте показано как получилось, красным цветом показано как я хотел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что нужно сделать чтобы достичь желаемого результата

Comment: Выделяете 2 верхних вертекса мышкой по очереди (второй с шифтом) или рамкой оба, потом `g` - переместить, `y` - только по оси y, и двигаете как нужно,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш объект имеет, что называется "неравномерное масштабирование". Чтобы это исправить, перейдите в режим Object Mode, затем нажмите <kbd>Ctlt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Apply Scale.

Многие операции производятся над объектом без учета масштаба и Bevel одна из них.